# Question about ElapsedMillis() library and state machines

Tags: millis

I'm making a sort of state machine with 3 states, and I'm actually doing some tests by configuring at the start of my code state=3. I've wired on each pin 2 leds, for a total of 12 leds. I'm using elapsedMillis library (https://github.com/pfeerick/elapsedMillis)  to make things a bit more easy and I'm stuck at 3rd state. At the 3rd state I would like that each couple of leds will stay on for 90ms, than goes of for 1ms. elapsedMillis library allows one to do something like that:

elapsedMillis timeElapsed; //declare global if you don't want it reset every time loop runs

```
#include "elapsedMillis.h"

const int pin0 = 12;
const int pin1 = 11;
const int pin2 = 10;
const int pin3 = 9;
const int pin4 = 8;
const int pin5 = 7;

unsigned long t1 = 500;
unsigned long waiting = 1000;
unsigned long t2 = 100;
unsigned long t3 = 50;
unsigned long t4 = 1;
unsigned long t5 = 90;
unsigned long startTime = 0;

int ledArray[] = {pin0, pin1, pin2, pin3, pin4, pin5};
int j, k, a, c = 0;
int state = 3;

elapsedMillis elapsedTime;
elapsedMillis timer1;
elapsedMillis timer2;
elapsedMillis timer3;
elapsedMillis timer4;
elapsedMillis timer5;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  switch (state) {

    case 0:
      // led accesi in modo scalare allo stato 0
      while (k <= 5)
      {

        if (timer1 >= t1)
        {
          if (j <= 5)
          {
            digitalWrite(ledArray[j], HIGH);
            j++;
            timer1 = 0;

          }
          k++;
          elapsedTime = 0;
        }

      }
      // attendo 1s poi vado allo stato 1

      if (elapsedTime >= waiting) {
        state = 1;
        elapsedTime = 0;
      }

      break;

    case 1:

      // led spenti rapidamente in modo scalare

      while (k >= 0) {
        if (timer2 >= t2)
        {
          if (j >= 0)
          {
            digitalWrite(ledArray[j], LOW);
            j--;
            timer2 = 0;
          }
          k--;
          elapsedTime = 0;
        }
      }
      // attendo 0.1s
      if (elapsedTime >= t2) {
        state = 2;

      }
      break;

    case 2:

      // led fade per 3 volte
      if (c <= 3)
      {
        while (a <= 255)
        {
          if (timer3 >= t3) {
            analogWrite(ledArray[3], a);
            timer3 = 0;
            a += 10;

          }

        }
        while (a >= 0)
        {
          if (timer3 >= t3) {
            analogWrite(ledArray[3], a);
            timer3 = 0;
            a -= 10;
          }
        }
        c++;
      }
      else {
        state = 3;
      }

      break;

    case 3:
      
      if (timer4 >= t5) {
        if (j <= 5) {
          digitalWrite(ledArray[j], HIGH);
          j++;
          timer4 = 0;
          if (timer5 >= t4) {
              digitalWrite(ledArray[j], LOW);
              timer5 = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      break;
  }
}
```

---

```
case 3:

  for (int ii = 0; ii <= 5; ii++) 
  {
    digitalWrite(ledArray[ii], ( (ii == j) && (timer4 < 90)));
  }
  
  if (timer4 > 91) {
    j += backwardScan ? -1 : 1 ;
    if (j > 5) {
      backwardScan = 1;
      j = 5;
    }
    if (j < 0) {
      backwardScan = 0;
      j = 0;
    }
    timer4 = 0;
  }
  break;
```

For the state3 I would like an effect like the "KITT" knight rider car in 80s TV show. Each couple of 2 leds should move back and forth... in shortly: first 2 leds stays on 90ms and 1ms off, then second 2 leds on 90ms and 1ms off.. etc...

It seems like the leds in the array goes on all together.

Comment: And what exactly is the actual problem? Please give a detailed description. Also: How are you seeing if it works? 1ms is too short of a pause to see with the human eye

Comment: For the state3 I would like an effect like the "KITT" knight rider car in 80s TV show. Each couple of 2 leds should move back and forth... in shortly: first 2 leds stays on 90ms and 1ms off, then second 2 leds on 90ms and 1ms off.. etc...

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? What exactly does it do different than expected? Please don't let us guess

Comment: seems like the leds in the array goes on all together

Comment: Guessing about case 3-- State variable `j` is which pair of leds to light, and.....Not sure... No state for back and forth, timing state is the diff between timer4 and timer5?  I'd guess you need another state variable to remember whether you are moving "back" or "forth".  In general with state machine logic, you should be able to identify exactly which state you are in, set the outputs accordingly, and then transition or not to the next state.  For instance, your code should be able to recognize how to set the KITT leds for the "middle pair, scanning forth-wards, on, 33ms to go" state.

Comment: Yes in state 3, variable j is to keep track of which pair of leds are you in, but my actual problem is how to have a led on for 90ms and 1ms off by using the timer4 and timer5 if needed. I have t4 that is variable for 90ms led ON and t5 that is led off for 1ms

Comment: ... You could handle the on & Xms to go state with the state of a timer, with `for(int ii=0,ii<=5,ii++){digitalWrite(edArray[ii],( (ii==j) && (timer4 <90) }}` and then whenever if(timer4>91)`, update  `backwards`, `j` and `timer4` to the appropriate next state.

Comment: mmmh sorry I can't read this well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain more state information to have 'case 3' work like a KITT-style back and forth LED scanner. I think you can do it with three state variables, `j` for which pair of LEDs is active, `backwardsScan` to say which way to go, and `timer4` to remember where in the 91ms cycle we are with the active pair of LEDs.

Try something like this:

```
...
int backwardsScan = 0;
...

case 3: // KITT-like scanning back and forth 90us/1us
  // j remembers which LED pair is active
  // backwardsScan remembers which direction to scan
  // timer4 handles the 90ms/1ms on-off cycle.
  // 
  // reset output leds appropriately for (j,timer4):
  for(int ii=0;ii<=5;ii++){
    digitalWrite(ledArray[ii],( (ii==j) && (timer4 <90))); 
  }
  // update KITT state based on (j,backwardsScan,timer4)
  if(timer4 > 91){ 
     j += backwardsScan? -1 : 1 ;
     if (j > 5){
        backwardsScan = 1;
        j = 5;
        }
     if (j < 0) {
        backwardsScan = 0;
        j = 0;
        }
     timer4 = 0;
     }

  break;
```

The main trick with state machines is being able to fully determine the complete state from what you are keeping track of--It should be memoryless, in that the state variable(s) fully specify the state, and you don't need to remember the prior state.  If you find you need to know more than one thing, you might need a vector or set of state variables.  One could map the whole led-backwardsScan-timer4 state vector into a single state variable (timer4, modulo 182ms for example,) but that would be unnecessarily complicated. Recognizing all the variables required to fully specify the state is important.

Comment: I noticed you write: "backwardsScan?" and the digitalWrite is not clear for me...

Comment: The  `( backwardsScan ? -1 : 1 )` is the ternary operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:  If  backwardsScan is true, it delivers the first value, -1  or if false, it delivers the second value +1.

Comment: I had to change this: for(int ii=0,ii<=5,ii++) with ";" not ,

Comment: The logic in the digitalWrite only writes HIGH to the active LED in the sub 90ms timer4  time, and LOW to all the other LEDs and to the active LED after 90ms.

Comment: I have lot of errors, trying now to fix the code...